# Error: file_get_contents() using from google maps to codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, google-maps

Hi i have this google maps that when a user inputs his address will get the lattitude and longitude in the registration page. After when i input the address then click register i want that, the json in the google maps will get the lattitude and longitude then save to my database. Im using `file_get_contents` to get the maps for google i encountered some error saying `Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: send of 68 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.` 
Heres my code below

```
 $address = urlencode($this->input->post('address'));
          $request = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" . $address . "&sensor=false");
          $json = json_decode($request, true);

          echo $json; exit;
```

why is that it will says `Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: send of 68 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.`? How will i able to solve this? can someone help me figured this out?Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/17854758/1164491

Comment: hi im looking for a php answer

Comment: not python. It seems your answer is in python

Comment: This error is not due to php, it is a system's problem, so it does not matter what is used by the link above.

Comment: My nickname is Cheery, which is not the same as Cherry. And SO is not a place for personal chatting.

Comment: Are you using a web filter on your machine (for example K9), that was causing me the same problem