# error: [Errno 10053] while submitting ajax form in Django

Tags: ajax, django

I saw a similar error already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854713/error-errno-10053) but that did not help to solve my problem. Besides the OP did not provided any information about what he was doing when he encountered that error (as others have said in the comments).

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am just trying to register the user to Django with ajax.

**What is the problem ?**

I get the following error the movement I submit the form:

```
[15/Jan/2018 17:49:37] "POST /authenticate/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 128, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 212, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 270, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 194, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 328, in write
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[15/Jan/2018 17:49:37] "POST /authenticate/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54896)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 654, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 713, in finish
    self.wfile.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 283, in close
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 307, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

**My code:**

***html:***

```
<div class="modal animated" id="signupModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <form id='registerForm'>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <input class="form-control" type="email" id="inputEmail">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputUsername">
           <input class="form-control" type="password" id="inputPassword">
           <input class="form-control" type="password" id="inputCPassword">      
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" id="signup-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Register </button> 
        </div>
     </div>
     </form>    
  </div>
</div>
```

***Ajax:***

```
$("#registerForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({    
     type: 'POST',
     url:  "/authenticate/register/",
     data: {
        'email' : $('#inputEmail').val(),
        'username': $('#inputUsername').val(),
        'password': $('#inputPassword').val(),
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
     },dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){                                                       
         if (data['errMsg'] != '')
           alert(data['errMsg']);
         else
           alert('Sending confirmation link...');
     }, error: function(xhr){
          alert('error!');
     }
  });
});
```

***views.py:***

```
class Register(View):       
    form_class = signupForm             
    def post(self, request):    
        data = {'errMsg': ''}          
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)       
        if form.is_valid():    
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False        
            to_email = form.cleaned_data['email']                           
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']            
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()                    

            # code to send confirmation email this code is big     
        else:               
            data = { 'errMsg': 'Something went wrong.' }                                

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

The strange thing is that the user gets registered even with that error. But why do I get this error and how would I fix it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally found the solution:**

I just moved `form` tag one step down inside `<div class="modal-content">` and it worked. :)

**solution:**

```
<div class="modal animated" id="signupModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <!-- from here to -->                                   
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id='registerForm'>{% csrf_token %} <!-- to here -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <input class="form-control" type="email" id="inputEmail">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputUsername">
           <input class="form-control" type="password" id="inputPassword">
           <input class="form-control" type="password" id="inputCPassword">      
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" id="signup-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Register </button> 
        </div>
        </form>  
     </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```