# Got ''An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine' error in firefox browser through selenium2library

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Getting following error while performing automation test through Selenium2Library for Robotframework...

> 11:54:56.623 INFO Typing text 'admin' into text field 'css=input.gwt-TextBox.field-input'. 
>   11:54:56.764 FAIL error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

And I am stucked here, It is working fine in Internet Explorer and Google chrome browser, but not in firefox browser, Can anyone help me to get ride from here.

I am using Robot Framework version 3.0.4, Selenium2Library 3.13.0, and firefox version: 61.1.0

Comment: Check your firewall - it might be blocking RF's selenium <-> geckodriver <-> FF binary communication in any of the 2 points. Also check your geckodriver is the expected/compatible version for both the installed selenium, and the FF's version.

Comment: If it is blocked by firewall, then none of keywords should work for firefox browser, even some suite is working and and some are not, it is peculiar issue ever I faced.

Comment: You're right, if it's fully blocked then it would've failed at the initial step, `Open Browser`; yet the error is explicit - the network connection was forcibly cut off - by something. Did you check the geckodriver, is it compatible with this FF version.

Comment: After some more findings, this issue is now resolved, it was happening due to timeout, after removing unexpected sleep time, it is working now in firefox as well, FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854713/error-errno-10053