# Python Django ConnectionAbortedError [WinError 10053]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So im facing a weird issue while making a request to my api. It works fine using something like postman. I get my response no issue but if I make a request from my frontend(on a seperate domain) the connection gets closed for some reason.

Here is my code

I make ajax request using axios

```
axios.get(mydomain/api/oauth)
 .then(response => {
   console.log(response)
 }).catch(error => {
 console.log(error.response.data)
})
```

which hits my backend method that should return a response like so

```
def oauth(request):
    auth_client = AuthClient(
        settings.CLIENT_ID,
        settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
        settings.REDIRECT_URI,
        settings.ENVIRONMENT
    )

    url = auth_client.get_authorization_url([Scopes.ACCOUNTING])
    request.session['state'] = auth_client.state_token
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

But at this point I get this alarm

```
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

And like I said if I make this same request through postman I get my response. So I don't know what I am missing. I have applied cors thinking maybe its because my frontend is on seperate domain from backend but no luck. Plus the alarm is kind of vague... anybody face similar issue?

Comment: You should see something in the browser console if cors is an issue.

Also is it server-side or client-side which is initiating the connection to the OAuth provider?

Comment: Yes agreed on the cors comment I just wanted to mention it, and on the server-side..

Comment: I am at a loss, everything seems as simple as possible, however,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854713/error-errno-10053 might have some relevant information.