# Simple SocketServer - client does not work after first request

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, socketserver

I'm trying to create a simple server. This server should be able to handle requests from multiple clients. The problem is, that after second request by one client, it raises: `socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True


class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):

        data = self.request.recv(1024)
        output = data
        response = "{}".format(output)
        self.request.sendall(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = _host, int(_port)
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address

    print "Running on: %s:%s" % (HOST, PORT)
    server.serve_forever()
```

**CONSOLE:**

```
CLIENT1->SERVER > anything
SERVER->CLIENT1 > anything
CLIENT1->SERVER > anything
socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

**EDIT:**

In case it helps:

**client.py**

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        data = raw_input()
        sock.sendall(data + "\n")
        received = sock.recv(1024)
        print "{}".format(received)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: If `handle` method behaves like described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8628089/5781248, the connection is closed when `handle` method returns i.e. after one request.

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/ might find some useful tidbits